# Math I did the program but need to know a little more

Tags: java

I did the problem but I only found out How to do it for one value of `x`? Here is the program.

```
public class PointsOnACircleV1 {
    public static void main(String[ ] args)
    {
    double r = 1;
    double x = 0.1;
    double equation1= Math.pow(r,2);
    double equation2= Math.pow(x,2);
    double y = Math.sqrt(equation1-equation2);

    System.out.println(y);

        }
}
```

I got the correct answer .99 (......)

I need mine to show multiple values of x. Here is how the output should be. Please help if you can.
[image: img]

Comment: [`Loops in programming`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(computing)#Loops) is the concept you need to grasp.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `for` loop.

**Related Documentation**

- [The for statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Answer (score 0):

In order to get it to print multiple values you first need to fill the "String [] args" but you need to ahve them as double to be able to multiply them with other values. In your case that's the X-values, so lets say over the code you posted

```
public class PointsOnACircleV1 {

 //initialize your array with your values
double [ ]  args = { 1.0, 0.9, 0.8,.... and so on until you reach 0.1, 0.0};
//you could fill it other more effective ways but just to show you!


public static void main(double[ ] args)
{
   double r = 1;
   // no need to fill this as you already done 
   // it double x = 0.1;

   for(Iterator<double> i = args.iterator(); args.hasNext(); ) 
   {
      //this is the number you want to multiply with
      double numbertomultiply = args.next();
      double equation1= Math.pow(r,2);
      double equation2= Math.pow(numbertomultiply,2);
      double y = Math.sqrt(equation1-equation2);

      System.out.println(y);
  }

}
```

Just written from my head havent checked it but just to give you a sample :)

EDIT Use the other answers to initialize your array.