# (x, y) coordinates of points on a circle of radius 1.0. I need help finding x2 and y2

Tags: java

My assessment was to do the program and the instructions are listed below.

> 1. The radius of the circle should be 1.0.
> 2. Use the appropriate Math class methods in your arithmetic expression(s).
> 3. The value of the x coordinate should change by 0.1 during initial testing. After the program is working verify that the increment can
>      also be 0.01, or 0.001 with only minor changes to the code.
> 4. Display the information in a neatly formatted table. (See expected output.) Use a Formatting Grid to save time developing the layout for
>      your output. Background: Recall from your algebra class that the
>      Pythagorean Theorem can be used to determine the x or y coordinate if
>      you know the radius of the circle and the value of either x or y.
>      Assume that you are dealing with a circle whose radius is 1. If you
>      iterate through successive values of x, then you can calculate the
>      corresponding value of y. Be sure to use methods of the Math class to
>      set up the arithmetic expression.

This is the circle: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NypKz.png

I did the program below.

```
public class PointsOnACircleV1 {
    public static void main(String[ ] args)
    {
   double[] x1 = { 1.0, 0.90, 0.80, 0.70, 0.60, 0.50, 0.40, 0.30, 0.20,
           0.10, 0.00, -0.10, -0.20, -0.30, -0.40, -0.50, -0.60, -0.70,
           -0.80, -0.90, -1.00 };

double r = 1;

    System.out.println("      Points on a Circle of Radius 1.0");
    System.out.println("       x1        y1        x2        y2");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");

for (int i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {
    double y1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r, 2) - Math.pow(x1[i], 2));
    double y2 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r, 2) - Math.pow(x1[i], 2));
    System.out.printf("%10.2f%10.2f%10.2f%10.2f%n", x1[i], y1, x1[i], y2);
}
    System.out.println("");
}
}
```

The output is supposed to be like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pywwJ.png

I am getting a different output. My output is coming like this.

```
      Points on a Circle of Radius 1.0
       x1        y1        x2        y2
---------------------------------------------
      1.00      0.00      1.00      0.00
      0.90      0.44      0.90      0.44
      0.80      0.60      0.80      0.60
      0.70      0.71      0.70      0.71
      0.60      0.80      0.60      0.80
      0.50      0.87      0.50      0.87
      0.40      0.92      0.40      0.92
      0.30      0.95      0.30      0.95
      0.20      0.98      0.20      0.98
      0.10      0.99      0.10      0.99
      0.00      1.00      0.00      1.00
     -0.10      0.99     -0.10      0.99
     -0.20      0.98     -0.20      0.98
     -0.30      0.95     -0.30      0.95
     -0.40      0.92     -0.40      0.92
     -0.50      0.87     -0.50      0.87
     -0.60      0.80     -0.60      0.80
     -0.70      0.71     -0.70      0.71
     -0.80      0.60     -0.80      0.60
     -0.90      0.44     -0.90      0.44
     -1.00      0.00     -1.00      0.00
```

Comment: Are you the same person that posted this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033716/math-i-did-the-program-but-need-to-know-a-little-more/

Comment: No, but the problem looks the same as mine.

Comment: OK, must be lots of people set the same problem. No worries, I was just curious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have calculated y1 and y2 to be the same value because the code is identical:

```
double y1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r, 2) - Math.pow(x1[i], 2));
double y2 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r, 2) - Math.pow(x1[i], 2));
```

It seems from the results that the value of y2 should just be the negation of y1. Try this instead:

```
double y1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r, 2) - Math.pow(x1[i], 2));
double y2 = -y1;
```

Answer (score 1):

It should also have a if statement, because the having only the other answer would give 
and output of -0.00.

```
    double y1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r, 2) - Math.pow(x1[i], 2));
    double y2 = 0.00;
    if (y1 != 0.00)
    {
        y2 = (-y1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to avoid -0.00 is this

```
    double y1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r, 2) - Math.pow(x1[i], 2));
    double y2 = 0 - y1;
```

This will save space and be quicker to run